# exception handling at db.SaveChanges() in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database

I have  one database called Test which includes one table called userinfo to save user information in my website

userinfo table contains

1.ID : primary key
2.name
3.password

http://s4.postimg.org/ut37i6y6x/window1.png

```
  namespace FirstApp.Models
   {
    using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class userinfo
    {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    }
    }
```

I edit account controller as the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using FirstApp.Models;


namespace FirstApp.Controllers
{
public class AccountController : Controller
{


 public TestEntities3 db = new TestEntities3();
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
 return View();
 }
 [HttpGet]

 public ActionResult Reg()
 {
 return View();

 }
    [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult Reg(Models.userinfo regclass)
    {

        var newuser = db.userinfoes.Create();
        db.userinfoes.Add(regclass);
       db.SaveChanges();
        return View(regclass);



    }
}
}
```

and view  as the following :

```
@model FirstApp.Models.userinfo
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Reg";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }

<h2>This is Registration page </h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
 {


<div>
@Html.LabelFor(u=>u.name)
@Html.TextBoxFor(u=>u.name)
</div>

<div>
@Html.LabelFor(u=>u.password)
@Html.PasswordFor(u=>u.password)
</div>

<input type="submit" />
 }
```

When I was test the above code it was work at first user only but when I tried enter the second user the following exception occurred:

http://s11.postimg.org/5hg84m16b/problem1.png

also in another tried this error message was appear:

A duplicate value cannot be inserted into a unique index. [ Table name = userinfo,Constraint name = PK_userinfo ]

Comment: Could you post how your entity has been configured?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing how your entities are configured, it is hard to debug this. However, I would expect a similiar exception to be thrown if you are using the Create function on DbSet and you are not overriding the primary key field properly. By default, the default value of the datatype will be assigned to the ID column field in your entity(which will be 0 for int column). So the first time you try to save the userinfo, a new userInfo with ID =0 will be created. The second time you try to save userInfo, you will hit primary key violation.

Possible solution would be to mark your ID column on the db to be an identity column and decorating the corresponding field in your c# entity with https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are creating a new user but never using it. You are adding the regclass directly to the context and then saving it.

You could create the new user (newUser) and then update the values in the new user to those in the regClass (ignoring the index) and then save the context (Meaning you never actually save the regclass object into the context - but you update the newUser you have just created)